# Another dynamic memory allocation bug

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to allocate memory for a multidimensional array (8 rows, 3 columns).

Here's the code for the allocation (I'm sure the error is clear for you)

```
char **ptr = (char **) malloc( sizeof(char) * 8);

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    ptr[i] = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * 3);
```

The crash happens when I reference this:

```
ptr[3][0];
```

> Unhandled exception at 0x0135144d in
>   xxxx.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing
>   location 0xabababab.

Are there any recommended references/readings for this kind of subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first `malloc()` is wrong. It should be:

```
malloc(sizeof(char*) * 8)
```

A `char*` is 4 byte (or 8 byte... see P.S) whereas `char` is 1 byte. When you write `ptr[3]` the compiler will assume that you want to access to the base address of `ptr` + `3*sizeof(char*)`. So you will access to memory that you didn't allocate.

**P.S:**

To be more precise, `char*` is 4 byte on 32 bit systems and 8 byte on 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know offhand any books on memory allocation, but any introductory C tutorial should explain it. As for your bug, your `for` loop only initializes the first 3 rows, instead of the 8 you allocated. It should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

Comment: @m4design The [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959370/another-dynamic-memory-allocation-bug/2959400#2959400) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959370/another-dynamic-memory-allocation-bug/2959407#2959407) are right too; there were two bugs, I didn't notice the `malloc` one, so make sure you fix both

Answer (score 4):

```
char **ptr = (char **) malloc( sizeof(char *) * 8);
```

Before, you were allocating space for 8 chars.  You want space for 8 pointers to char.

Michael pointed out the other error, writing the first char from a  string you never allocated.

It may help if you use constants, like:

```
const int STRING_COUNT = 8;
const int STRING_LEN = 2;

char **ptr = (char **) malloc( sizeof(char *) * STRING_COUNT);
```

Answer (score 3):

`ptr` is an array of 8 pointers, not `char`s, so the first line should be:

```
char **ptr = (char **) malloc( sizeof(char*) * 8)
```

Because there are 8 pointers, the loop should go from 0 to 7:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

You can also consider using a less prone to errors version of the first line:

```
char **ptr = (char **) malloc( sizeof(*ptr) * 8)
```

And the last one:

```
ptr[i] = (char *) malloc( sizeof(*ptr[i]) * 3);
```

The rule is: always take `sizeof` of dereferenced lvalue. If lvalue is `ptr`, then you need `sizeof(*ptr)`. `ptr[i]` becomes `sizeof(*ptr[i])`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several errors/inconsistencies in your code, but the first major one is the wrong `sizeof` in the first allocation. The error that you made could have easily been avoided if you followed some good-practice guidelines:

**(1)** As much as possible avoid using type names in *statements*. Type names belong in *declarations*, not in statements.

**(2)** Don't cast the result of memory allocation functions.

The first allocation should have looked as follows

```
char **ptr = malloc( 8 * sizeof *ptr );
```

Try to remember this as a generic pattern: `malloc` requestes should normally look as follows

```
pointer = malloc( count * sizeof *pointer );
```

Note: no type names are mentioned in the above statement.

Of course, you should also make up your mind about the first size of your 2D array. You attempt to allocate 8, then you only initialize 3. Why?

Comment: unfortunately, C++ requires you to cast, so you need to if you want to write code that is valid for both.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: Yes, but this question is tagged C. Also, the issue of "writing code that is valid for both" normally applies to header files only. Unless you are writing an inline function or a macro in a header file, the matter of casing (or not casting) `malloc` usually doesn't arise with relation to C++ compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

First, as others have pointed out, your initial malloc should be

> malloc(sizeof(char *) * 8)

Second, you are initializing the first **three** elements in the 8-element array, but `ptr[3][0]` refers to the **fourth** element. Thus the crash.